# I'm looking for the title of an adult romance novel of the supernatural/fantasy genre

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult, romantic-interest

Please note that this story is set in a modern world.

First off, the story involved a main male lead who was some sort of dark mage and described as "unkempt" or "wild", a complete opposite to the main female lead who liked cleanliness. Which, because of that, made her female friend doubtful the female lead would be attracted to the male lead.

Another thing I remember: The male lead held certain tattoos or runes on his body that acted as hot keys for certain magic spells, enabling him to cast certain spells instantly. I think he used a teleportation spell in front of the female lead, making her impressed since that is a pretty difficult spell to execute.

The female lead, I think, worked at a magical library that held numerous grimoires. Also, I recall that the girl friend of the female lead had romantic interest in a very cold, indifferent male Angel.

Last, the male lead had a infamous dark mage enemy who plotted to use the female lead against him.

Comment: Could this be a comic, *Death Vigil*?

Comment: I searched the title, but no, it isnt what I was looking for. The story I'm talking of is a romance novel, nota comic. Ever read the Lords of the underworld series? If so, the novel is similar to those type of stories

Comment: Btw, welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE! This is a great first post, good job!

Comment: Check this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120619214945AAJm0mz

Comment: Could this be one of *Constantine* novels?

Comment: First off,thanks for the welcome Gallifreian. (Nice doctor who reference btw) but no, it isn't and that link didn't help either unfortunately

Comment: And the warded man novel that it, the link, mentioned I had already read. Though I stopped after book two, since what happened to one, or rather two, of the more important female characters left a sour taste in my mouth. But thanks for the welcome, again, and for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Mindy Klasky novel as it seems to have a similar 'librarian romance' theme. Possibly Magic and the Modern Girl?

The main character is a very clean-centric lady, and a librarian for a magical archive. She is also a witch who hasn't really come into her powers, or rather her powers are pretty spectacularly good at misfiring. The male romantic interest (whose name I cannot entirely remember) does have tattoos and is also her magical teacher/guardian person.

Comment: Could be. Can you remember any plot details that might fit the description in the question?

Comment: The main character is a very clean-centric lady, and a librarian for a magical archive. She is also a witch who hasn't really come into her powers, or rather her powers are pretty spectacularly good at misfiring. The male romantic interest (whose name I cannot entirely remember) does have tattoos and is also her magical teacher/guardian person.

Comment: Those elements do fit. I skimmed through the book, though, and there does not seem to be an angel, a teleportation spell, and so forth. Is it maybe part of a series?

Comment: I believe that it is part of the Jane Madison novels, either the second or the third.

Comment: Mmmk, I could look at the others....

Comment: I don't know, if it's a series I don't think they would be a continuation of the book I'm talking of but rather focusing on other characters within the same universe.  I will check them out, see if they fit.

Comment: Ah..I just checked. No, sadly. The book I was reading had pretty explicit scenes between the main characters. An adult supernatural romance novel.  The hammer Madison novels dont seem like they would be of that genre. And I know the cover was different. I will keep searching, though. Thank for the help, and your time :)